# Is there any to track what layer a user is currently viewing in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Is there anyway with the layer control to determine what layer is currently active for a user. Say for example the user selected and is using the grayscale layer or for example the user selected and is using the streets layer?

How could you track which layer a user is on in this in this example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

The leaflet layer control usage is not document on how to track which layer is currently selected and being used by a user.

I need to track which layer a person is actively viewing for my code.

Thank you so much in advance!

Dan

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about tile layers.

Yes it is possible using the [ActiveLayers leaflet plugin](https://github.com/vogdb/Leaflet.ActiveLayers). This github project page is pretty well documented.

You can ask ActiveLayers control which base layer and which overlay layer are active.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will check out this plugin!